# Excel condition comparing two cells then fetching data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm relearning Microsoft Excel after moving to Numbers a couple years back. I have an idea in mind that I would like to put in practice, but having a rather hard time trying to do. I'm not sure if this is possible, but it should be if I can remember correctly.

Assume I have a list of origins and destination, each of these have their own tariff.

> CGK-SIN = $0.25 
>   SIN-CGK = $0.50 
>   CGK-KUL = $1.10 
>   KUL-CGK = $1.50 
>   KUL-SIN = $0.75 
>   SIN-KUL = $0.85

Above is an example of the tariff table. I know that I can prepare this in a separate sheet and refer to this, however I'm having trouble trying to set condition for the two cells (Origin, Destination) to fetch the rates.

[image: Visual depiction of the actual excel table.]

I want the tariff field to compare the data of Origin and Destination field. Kinda like:

```
if
origin = "CGK"
destination = "SIN"

then
tariff = "$0.25"

Elseif...
```

And so on and so forth. I hope I pushed across what I am trying to achieve clearly. Apologies if the coding is wrong, I haven't coded in years! (Self thought VB and C++ as a kid, not extensively though)

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: better make a real table (having source at top and target at the left) and then get the values by crossing them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a table like this:
[image]

In H1 would be:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(G1,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(F1,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

Which can simply be copied down...

no need for VBA... ...but IF you want it to be done via VBA to get an UDF there 2 ways to do it.

#1 as Symbiotic sheet/VBA

```
Public Function getTarif(source, dest) As Double
  With Sheet1
    source = Application.Match(source, .Range("B1:D1"), 0)
    dest = Application.Match(dest, .Range("B1:D1"), 0)
    If IsNumeric(source) And IsNumeric(dest) Then getTarif = .Cells(source + 1, dest + 1).Value
  End With
End Function
```

#2 full VBA

```
Public Function getTarif(source, dest) As Double
  Dim a, b
  a = Array("CGK", "SIN", "KUL")
  b = Array(Array(0, 0.5, 1.5), _
            Array(0.25, 0, 0.75), _
            Array(1.1, 0.85, 0))
  source = Application.Match(source, a, 0) - 1
  dest = Application.Match(dest, a, 0) - 1
  If IsNumeric(source) And IsNumeric(dest) Then getTarif = b(source)(dest)
End Function
```

#1 needs a table like in the picture (in the worksheet with the codename Sheet1 which can be changed)
Neither #1 nor #2 is case sensitive so `=getTarif("siN","kUl")` will still output 0.85.

Comment: I don't really want it in VBA, I was just trying to explain better I suppose. Can this be done on another sheet? I'd like my first sheet like an interface and clean.

Comment: @Excl sure... doing it in sheet1 while having the table in sheet2 the formula would be `=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$D$4,MATCH(G1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(F1,Sheet2!$B$1:$D$1,0))`... just do not mix up F1 and G1 :)

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks, took me a while, couldn't figure it out. Got it now!